# Python re.findall expected string

Tags: python, subprocess, python-re, gnu-screen, findall

I want to search for a word in my string with `re.findall`. The Code is the following:

```
def check_status():
   p1 = subprocess.run(["screen", "-ls"], shell=False)
   p2 = re.findall("myscreen", p1)
   print(p2)
```

The return from `p1` looks like this:

```
There are screens on:
    2420454.myscreen        (12/25/2021 01:15:17 PM)        (Detached)
    6066.bot                (12/14/2021 07:11:52 PM)        (Detached)
```

If I execute this function, I get the following error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 240, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I searched for this problem already but found nothing.

I'm using Python 3.10

Comment: Since it wants a string, you could cast `p1` to a string by doing `str(p1)`

Comment: If I do `str(p1)`, the function gives me an empty array back like this: `[]`

Comment: You probably need to set `capture_output=True` on `subprocess.run`and then look at `p1.stdout` or use one of the other `subprocess` methods to get the data back from the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.run` returns a `CompletedProcess` object. You want to add `capture_output=True` and `text=True` to the keyword arguments, and apply the regular expression to its `stdout` member:

```
p2 = re.findall('myprocess', p1.stdout)
```

.. though of course, you don't need a regular expression to look for a static string:

```
p2 = 'myprocess' in p1.stdout
```

If you want to extract the screen ID, maybe loop over `stdout.splitlines()` and extract the first token from the matching lines.

```
p2 = []
for line in p1.stdout.splitlines():
    if 'myprocess' in line:
        p2.append(line.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Before your Answer, I put the `subprocess.run` command in a variable. Is that the same or is my way less secure?

Comment: I don't understand. Like `cmd = ['screen', '-ls']; p1 = subprocess.run(cmd)`? Literally no difference from a security point of view, but the useless variable might offend sensitive eyes (but not much).

Comment: I used like this: `p1 = subprocess.run(["screen", "-ls"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
`p2 = ','.join(str(x) for x in re.findall(INSTANCE_NAME, str(p1)))`

Comment: I can see no security implications there either. You still don't need a regex, but if you insist on using one, compiling it once and putting that in a variable might actually make sense for efficiency. `str(p1)` looks very wrong; why do you not use the `stdout` attribute?

Comment: I didn't know that before, so I will use your version. My version is good if you want to grep the process name for some reason. I used this as return value before. Thanks mate

Comment: You clearly already know the process name. I updated to show how to extract the screen ID from the search results.

Comment: In my case, it worked with `p2 = 'myprocess' in str(p1.stdout)`. You have to place `str()` around `p1.stdout`.

Comment: Actually, the proper fix is to add `text=True`; updated answer.